# Does send(),transfer() etc calls implicitly reduces contract balance?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

```
L1: require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
L2: require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
L3: _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount);
L4: _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
```

Is line L3 compulsory to reduce the contract balance?
Also if the same is not done will that not lead to a similar issue of double spending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While implementing the ERC20 Token you'd better off using a library like OpenZepplin, then you don't need to implement `send/transfer` at all.

However, if you don't want to use the library, then you're on your own, so yes you need the line L3 (and L4) to keep track of the token balance.